# Why are the meanings of .. and ... flipped between git diff and git log?

Tags: git

Take for instance an example repo with this history graph:

```
$ git log --all --graph --oneline
* 691d454 (HEAD -> branch-b) branch-b-2
* c3bd488 branch-b
| * f5756ff (branch-a) branch-a-2
| * de00ec4 branch-a
|/  
* 5ad3b15 (root) root
```

Now, compare `git diff branch-a..branch-b`

```
diff --git a/f b/f
index af31a64..e7791f3 100644
--- a/f
+++ b/f
@@ -1 +1 @@
-branch-a-2
+branch-b-2
```

with `git diff branch-a...branch-b`

```
diff --git a/f b/f
index d8649da..e7791f3 100644
--- a/f
+++ b/f
@@ -1 +1 @@
-root
+branch-b-2
```

with `git log --oneline branch-a..branch-b`

```
691d454 (HEAD -> branch-b) branch-b-2
c3bd488 branch-b
```

with `git log --oneline branch-a...branch-b`

```
691d454 (HEAD -> branch-b) branch-b-2
c3bd488 branch-b
de00ec4 branch-a
f5756ff (branch-a) branch-a-2
```

Basically, we're seeing this:

```
|------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|      | branch-a..branch-b                   | branch-a...branch-b                  |
|------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
| log  | root -> branch-b                     | branch-a -> branch-b                 |
|      | (root, branch-b]                     | [branch-a, branch-b]                 |
|      | changes introduced in branch-b       | difference from branch-a to branch-b |
|------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
| diff | branch-a -> branch-b                 | root -> branch-b                     |
|      | [branch-a, branch-b]                 | (root, branch-b]                     |
|      | difference from branch-a to branch-b | changes introduced in branch-b       |
|------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
```

What this implies is that if you want to see the changes done in a branch that forks off from master as a list of commits, `git log master..branch` will show you. However, if you want to see those same changes as a diff that combines those commits, you'll have to switch to `...` like so, `git diff master...branch`. This is something that I find myself doing very frequently, and so is a minor annoyance I've been wondering about for a while.

Is there a design reason? It seems to only be an inconsistency.

EDIT: To clarify, I know what `..` and `...` translate to in both `diff` and `log`. My question could be rephrased as: Wouldn't it make more sense for either to be flipped so they'd be consistent with one another? For example, if `git diff branch-a..branch-b` meant `git diff $(git merge-base branch-a branch-b) branch-b` and `git diff branch-a...branch-b` meant `git diff branch-a branch-b`, then `diff` would be consistent with `log`. So, why was this not the case?

EDIT 2: In the paragraph below the table, I gave a practical example of how `git diff master...branch` is the analogous of `git log master..branch`. For the other case, if you want to get the listing of commits that separates `master` from `branch` (i.e. the commits that represent the difference between the 2), you'd use `git log master...branch`, and if you want the diff that represents that same difference, you'd use `git diff master..branch`.

EDIT 3: I tried to make the table more clear. The use of brackets and parenthesis is [math interval notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(mathematics)#Intervals).

EDIT 4: Transposed the table so it fits better.

Comment: maybe I'm reading your table incorrectly, but I'm not seeing why `log branch-a..branch-b` is `root -> branch-b`? (that is: I don't see `5ad3b15` in the output)

Comment: @AnthonySottile The point is that it's showing the commits from `root` to `branch-b` in the sense that it doesn't include the changes of `branch-a`. If `branch-b` had more commits, they'd also appear; all from `root` to `branch-b` not including the bound on root. This also aligns with `diff` with `...` in that it doesn't include the change of `5ad3b15`, otherwise you wouldn't see the removal of the `root` line and only see the addition of the `branch-b` line to a previously non-existant file.

Comment: @zerkms I understand it's documented. I'm looking for the design reason.

Comment: @JoL right, I should have read the complete answer :-D sorry

Comment: I added a couple commits to help avoid the confusion over the single line log output.

Comment: I believe there is no good explanation. It's just the way it is. You could check the git history and see if there is any explanation or discussion

Comment: @axiac I checked, just in case, but it doesn't explain the reason for the inconsistency. Like max630 said, I'll probably need to check git's git history to see if the reason is stated anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

They're not (flipped).  Rather, `..` in `git diff` has the special meaning that it has *no* meaning, and `...` in `git diff` has a special meaning unique to `git diff`, not found in any other Git command.

Your particular input graph <s>is ...</s> *was*, before the edit :-) ... too small to show the real difference.  If you had more commits after the two branches diverged, you could see more.

#### Long

Let's look at `git diff` first because it is simpler.  What `git diff` does, in these particular cases—there are special cases for *combined diffs* but they do not apply here; and we can diff a commit vs our work-tree or vs our index, which we're not doing here—is *pick two individual commits and compare them*.

To name the two commits to compare, I prefer to write:

```
git diff <commit1> <commit2>
```

However, you can, if you prefer, write:

```
git diff <commit1>..<commit2>
```

These mean *exactly the same thing*, always.<sup>1</sup>  Git just pretends you did not write the `..` after all.  This is true whether you use hash IDs here, or branch names like `master`, or remote-tracking names like `origin/master`, or any mix of these.

Note that the order of the two commit name-or-hash-IDs matters: the output of `git diff` is a set of instructions, telling you how to change the first commit so that you would get the second commit, if you followed all the instructions.

If you write:

```
git diff <commit1>...<commit2>
```

Git will *still* compare two commits:<sup>2</sup> Git will find the *merge base* between the two given commits, then compare that merge base commit to the second listed commit.  That is, this is the same as the shell-style expansion:

```
git diff $(git merge-base <commit1> <commit2>) commit2
```

Here, as before, the order matters: the merge base is the same,<sup>3</sup> regardless of the order of the two commits, but that merge base is compared with the second-listed commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, almost always!  There are some corner cases you can tickle if you list a *third* commit on the command line, where it acts like you used the three-dot syntax.  I would argue that these are a bug in `git diff`, although it's always possible that someone has come to depend on them.

<sup>2</sup>There's another corner case here, and it definitely *is* a bug: if there is more than one merge base, `git diff` produces a combined diff.  That's not the intent of the three-dot syntax, which is why it's a bug.

<sup>3</sup>This assumes you do not tickle the bug in footnote 2.  When there is a single merge base for multiple commits, the order is irrelevant, but when there are multiple merge bases, the order of the inputs may affect the order of the outputs.

---

For `git log` and most other Git commands, though, `..` and `...` have quite a different meaning.  As you no doubt know by now, `<commit1>..<commit2>` is shorthand for `<commit2> ^<commit1>`.  We can see this with `git rev-parse`:

```
$ git rev-parse master..origin/maint
468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0
^ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c
```

Here `origin/maint` translates to the first (un-negated) hash ID, and `master` translates to the second (negated) one.  These tell Git that, as it walks the commit graph, it should select commits that are reachable from `468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0` (the positive reference) while rejecting commits that are reachable from `ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c` (the negative reference).  That means *all* such commits, which may be many commits.  A command like `git log`, walking through the commit graph, will show all selected commits.

The three-dot notation is trickier, but translates internally into the same kind of positive and negative reference:

```
$ git rev-parse master...origin/maint
468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0
ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c
^468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0
```

Here, the two positive references are the hash IDs associated with `origin/maint` and `master` as before, and the negative reference is a result of the point(s) where the subgraphs selected by these start-points rejoin.  There is only one such point in this particular case—so this matches the output from `git merge-base` as we will see in a moment—though some sub-graphs that diverge and merge in complex ways can have multiple such points:

```
$ git merge-base master origin/maint
468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0
```

(It's these same kinds of complex graphs that can result in multiple merge bases, though the code that implements `...` is simpler than the code that finds merge bases.)

If you have a graph like this one:

```
     C--D   <-- br1
    /
A--B
    \
     E--F   <-- br2
```

the three-dot syntax `br1...br2` selects commits `C-D` and `E-F` for commands that walk the graph like `git log`, but selects commits `B` and `F` respectively for `git diff` (and *only* for `git diff`).  The two-dot syntax `br1..br2` selects commits `E-F` for `git log` and the like, and compares commits `D` and `F` respectively for `git diff` (and *only* for `git diff`).

Comment: The thing is, I already know what they translate to. I guess my question could be rephrased, "wouldn't it make more sense for either diff's or log's `...` and `..` to be flipped so they'd be consistent with one another?" I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: Check out the last paragraph: `git diff` *won't* resemble `git log` when using `..` this way, as you wind up comparing commits `D` and `F` in `git diff` but never see commit `D` at all in `git log`.

Comment: Right, my question is "why?" on that last paragraph and your comment. :) For example, why wasn't `git log` made to see `D` when using `..` but not when using `...`, or switch `diff`s meanings likewise so `log` and `diff` would be consistent with one another and you wouldn't need to describe the difference between `diff` and `log` in the last paragraph.

Comment: There's always going to be some fundamental difference here because `git log` will walk *all* selected commits, so if there were five commits reachable from `br2` that were not reachable from `br1`, `git log br1..br2` would show all five of those, but `git diff` will just compare two commits. I think the reason `A..B` excludes `A` and includes `B` is to make it resemble a half-open interval like `(1..4]`. In the end, though, these graph selection operators *don't* resemble half-open intervals, so that idea might be a bad one. I'd also argue that allowing `git diff A..B` is just wrong...

Comment: ... since it's going to mean `git diff A B` and Git could just force users to write that. But that's not what the Git authors chose.

Comment: There wouldn't be a difference if either were flipped, though, and that's what I'm getting at. `git diff` would then show the diff that represents the combination those 5 commits like it does with `br1...br2`, right now.